# Number of p-adic strings of length l without t-consecutive zeros

Tags: co.combinatorics

Firstly I define a p-adic string of length l as a list $a = [a_1,...,a_l]$ where $0 \leq a_i \leq p-1$ for $i \in [l] $. Then what is the number of such lists without t- consecutive zeros? My approach: break the l-length string into $l/t$ lists of size t, and now we can get an upper bound of $(p^t - 1)^{l/t}$. My question is can we improve this bound as if we take a fixed $l$ and make $p$ very large this bound does not become $o(p^l)$, but if we fix $p$ and let $l$ be very large, then we get $o(p^l)$. Can we, in general, say that the number of such lists is $o(p^l)$? Furthermore, suppose we have m such p-adic strings such that none of them has t - consecutive zeros at the same place the can we say number of such strings is $o(p^{ml})$.

Comment: The generating function (in the variable $z$) for the exact number of strings of length $ℓ$ in an alphabet of size $p$ (including a “zero”) with no $t$ consecutive zeros is: $(1-z^t)/(1-p z-(1-p)z^{t+1})$; meaning the number of strings is the coefficient of $z^\ell$ in the power series expansion of this rational function. This answers your question (for a certain definition of “answer”), but I'm not sure whether you can get any useful asymptotics out of this. Should I post more details as an answer?

Comment: @Gro-Tsen can you expand or send a link on why this power-series gives an exact count. It will be extremely helpful

Comment: I asked this question on MSE way back in April 2014! You can find it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/775863/37122

Comment: @BenjaminDickman It's surprising that none of the answers you got on MSE makes even a passing mention of rational languages or finite automata. I fear the fact that the generating function of a rational language is itself rational (and the algorithm to compute it from an automaton) is far less well-known that it deserves to be.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Would definitely welcome an answer there, too; or I can link to this one. I'm not sure what the intersection of "MSE" and "over 9 years ago" collectively led to in terms of answer variety, quality, etc.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman You can link to this MO question from the comments in your MSE question, since there are already valid answers I don't think it's worth copying mine on MSE. (It's also not entirely clear to me whether the questions are, indeed, identical, because of the ambiguity of the phrase “without $c$ consecutive occurrences of a digit”: does this mean “of any digit” or “of a fixed specified digit which we might call ‘zero’”? The present question unambiguously calls for the latter interpretation.)

Comment: Another reference, with some asymptotic data, is https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0898122109005744.

Answer (score 2):

As requested in the comments, here is a way of computing the generating function for the exact number of strings of length $\ell$ in an alphabet $\Sigma$ of size $p$ (including a “zero”) that do not contain $m$ consecutive zeros.  (I'm renaming the $t$ in the question to $m$.)  This is a straightforward application of the algorithm that computes the generating function for any rational language on a finite alphabet from a finite automaton recognizing the language in question (here the DFA has $m+1$ states, labeled $0$ through $m-1$ and $\bot$, described implicitly below: $L_q$ defined below is the set of words which bring the automaton to state $q$).

(In what follows, the phrase “the generating function for the language $L$” means $f := \sum_{\ell=0}^{+\infty} c_\ell z^\ell \in \mathbb{C}[[z]]$ where $z$ is a formal indeterminate and $c_\ell := \#\{w \in L : |w|=\ell\}$ is the number of words of length $\ell$ in $L$.  For example, the generating function of the language $\Sigma^*$ of all words on an alphabet of size $p$ is $1 + pz + p^2z^2 + \cdots = \frac{1}{1-pz}$.)

For $0\leq i\leq m-1$, let $L_i$ be the set of words on $\Sigma$ which **(a)** do not contain $m$ consecutive zeros (anywhere), *and additionally* **(b)** end in precisely $i$ zeros.  Furthermore, let $L_\bot$ be the set of words which **do** contain $m$ consecutive zeros (somewhere).  Let $f_0,\ldots,f_{m-1},f_\bot$ be the generating functions for $L_0,\ldots,L_{m-1},L_\bot$ respectively.  (Evidently, $\Sigma^*$ is the disjoint union of $L_0,\ldots,L_{m-1},L_\bot$, so $f_0+\cdots+f_{m-1}+f_\bot = \frac{1}{1-pz}$.)  Our goal is to compute the generating function $g := f_0+\cdots+f_{m-1}$ of $L_0\cup\cdots\cup L_{m-1}$.

Now a word in $L_0$ is either the empty word or is obtained by adding one of the $p-1$ nonzero symbols at the end of a (uniquely defined) word in $L_0\cup\cdots\cup L_{m-1}$.  This means that:

- $f_0 = 1 + (p-1)z f_0 + \cdots + (p-1)z f_{m-1}$

A word in $L_{i+1}$ for $0\leq i\leq m-2$, on the other hand, is obtained by adding a zero at the end of a (uniquely defined) word in $L_i$.  In other words:

- $f_{i+1} = z f_i$

Finally, for a word of length $\ell$ in $L_\bot$, there are two possibilities: either the $\ell-1$ first letters are in $L_{m-1}$ and the last letter is a zero, or the $\ell-1$ first letters are already in $L_\bot$ (and the last letter is anything).  This translates as:

- $f_\bot = z f_{m-1} + p z f_\bot$

To summarize, we have the following linear relation on $(f_0,\ldots,f_{m-1},f_\bot)$:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}f_0\\f_1\\f_2\\\vdots\\f_\bot\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
(p-1)z&(p-1)z&\cdots&(p-1)z&0\\
z&0&\cdots&0&0\\
0&z&\cdots&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&\cdots&z&pz\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}f_0\\f_1\\f_2\\\vdots\\f_\bot\end{pmatrix}
$$

Call $M$ the $(m+1)\times(m+1)$ matrix with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}[[z]]$ appearing above, so we are to solve $\vec f = \vec e + M \vec f$ where $\vec f$ is the column vector $(f_0,\ldots,f_{m-1},f_\bot)$ and $\vec e$ is the column vector $(1,0,\ldots,0)$.  Its unique solution is $\vec f = (1-M)^{-1}\, \vec e$ since $1-M$ is invertible since it is congruent to $1$ mod $(z)$.

Now I claim that the solution is given by:

- $f_i = z^i/(1 - (p-1)\,z\,(1+\cdots+z^{m-1}))$ for $0\leq i\leq m-1$
- $f_\bot = z^m/((1-pz)\, (1 - (p-1)\,z\,(1+\cdots+z^{m-1})))$

Since the solution is unique, this is proved by simply checking that the expressions in question satisfy the linear relations written above, which is straightforward.

Finally the desired generating function is $g := f_0+\cdots+f_{m-1} = \frac{1}{1-pz} - f_\bot$.  Rewriting $1+\cdots+z^{m-1}$ as $(1-z^m)/(1-z)$ and putting $\frac{1}{1-pz} - \frac{1}{(1-pz)\, (1 - (p-1)\,z\,\frac{1-z^m}{1-z})}$ on a common denominator, this gives the following final generating function:
$$
\frac{1-z^m}{1-pz-z^{m+1}+pz^{m+1}}
$$
for the words that do not contain $m$ consecutive zeros.

Comment: Thank you, that was quite a neat trick to find the generating function